# From where get subscription key for api.ai chatbot to be deployed on Microsoft Cortana

Tags: chatbot, cortana, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to build a chatbot using api.ai. I want to integrate this bot with Microsoft Cortana. I followed every step given at this link: https://docs.api.ai/docs/cortana-integration but then to initialize api.ai instance, I have written following code. Client access token is available to me. My question here is from where to get the **subscription key**?

```
var config = new AIConfiguration("String subscription key",
                       "String client_access_token",
                       SupportedLanguage.English);

            apiAi = new ApiAi(config);
            apiAi.DataService.PersistSessionId();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about the code that you have because at the URL mentioned : https://docs.api.ai/docs/cortana-integration, the code is something like this:

`var config = new AIConfiguration("YOUR_CLIENT_ACCESS_TOKEN",                                  SupportedLanguage.English);`

So, all you will need is just the Client Access Token, which is available from the Agent Settings page in API.AI

Comment: yes function **AIConfiguration** won't allow you to use two parameters  only i.e. (CLIENT_ACCESS_TOKEN & SupportedLanguage).  Their documentation is wrong. Function defination contains three parameters that are as I mentioned above.

Comment: @TejasBramhecha - Were you able to figure it out?